# Selecting multiple checkboxes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Consider the following:

```
$('#num-locations input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    var location = e.target.dataset.location;

    $('.manage-wrapper').each(function() {
      var city = $(this).data('city');
      if (city !== location) {
        $(this).toggleClass('hide-on-location');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('.hide-on-location').toggleClass('hide-on-location');
  }
});
```

So with in this selector: `#num-locations input[type="checkbox"]` I check if the value is checked, if so I apply a class to any `.manage-wrapper` that doesn't match the `data-` attribute.

When you uncheck said checkbox, it removes the class. Great.

This works for one checkbox with in the `#num-locations input[type="checkbox"]` How ever, I have multiple check boxes with in `#num-locations` and I cannot target them individually because they are added dynamically.

Question:

*How do I write this such that if you check 1 or more checkboxes that it will toggle the class and if you uncheck one or more it untoggles the class?*

**Example data**, all elements that don't match a data-location of `Sample` would be hidden, great. Uncheck, `Sample` is now shown.

Now what about checking `Sample` and `Crab Apple`, any element that doesn't match `Sample` or `Crab Apple` needs to be hidden, when I uncheck `Crab Apple`, all elements that match `Crab Apple` should be shown but all elements that don't match `Sample` Should still be hidden.

**I cannot check for specific attributes, because this is dynamic.**

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly OP, it sounds like you're trying to implement checkbox-based filtering...?

Comment: @TylerRoper yes that’s correct and my current solution works when one check box is clicked and unclicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to create a generic set of filtering checkboxes. If so, the code below should help you out. I mocked up the HTML as you hadn't included it in your question, however I think it should be adequate.

Here are some of the methods used.

- [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to change our collection of *elements* into a collection of their *`data-city`* values
- [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to return the data values *as an `Array`*
- [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to narrow down our `manage-wrapper` selection to only those *not* checked

I've also included comments in the code itself to document each step in a bit more detail.

```js
$("#num-locations input[type=checkbox]").on("click", refreshFilters);

function refreshFilters() {
  var $checkedInputs = $("#num-locations input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var $manageWrappers = $(".manage-wrapper");
  
  $manageWrappers.removeClass("hide-on-location");  //Start with all shown
  if (!$checkedInputs.length) return;               //If nothing is checked, exit early

  //Get the checked cities as an array, e.g. ["New York", "Chicago"]
  var cities = $checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).data("city") }).get();
  
  //Find any .manage-wrapper whose data-location is NOT in that array, and hide it
  $manageWrappers
    .filter(function() { return !cities.includes($(this).data("location")); })
    .addClass("hide-on-location");
}
```

```css
  
.hide-on-location { display: none; }
#num-locations { margin-bottom: 10px; }
.manage-wrapper { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num-locations">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" data-city="New York"> <label for="cb1">New York</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" data-city="Seattle">  <label for="cb2">Seattle</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" data-city="Chicago">  <label for="cb3">Chicago</label>
</div>

<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="New York">New York</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="Seattle">Seattle</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="New York">New York</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="Chicago">Chicago</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="New York">New York</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="Chicago">Chicago</div>
<div class="manage-wrapper" data-location="Seattle">Seattle</div>
```